# Is there any way to select only the layer of which the features have been selected?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select

Is there any way to select only the layer of which the features have been selected? That is, if I have selected some roads then I want only the road layer to be selected.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say you want only the road layer to be "selected"?

Answer (score 6):

Right click on layer name: Selection -> Make This The Only Selectable Layer

Fine control of selectable layers:
In table of Contents switch to List by Selection view and then choose which layer are selectable:
[image]